# Как менять значение переменной скрипта из другого скрипта при нажатии на Button?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

GetComponent вообще никак не помогает, либо лезу ошибки, либо вообще ничего не происходит. Абсолютно все, что я  находил в интернете не помогает. Чувствую себя каким-то особенным.
У меня есть скрипт Cut

```
public class Cut : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject[] weed = new GameObject[4];
    public Text Gramm;
    public int gr;
    public Text Hr;
    private int zero;
    public GameObject hand;

    public void OnCut()
    {
        zero = 0;
        Hr.text=zero + "";
        gr += 200;
        Gramm.text = gr + "";
        weed[0].SetActive(true);
        weed[2].SetActive(false);
        weed[3].SetActive(false);
        hand.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

И мне нужно что-то написать в скрипте Sell, что меняла бы переменную gr из скрипта Cut.
Что нужно писать?

Answer (score 1):

Первое: Вопрос сформулирова АБСОЛЮТНО не четко. Формулируй вопросы так что бы тебя понимали ВСЕ. Сейчас это просто набор обрывчастых мыслей.

Второе: Для того, что бы из одного скрипта найти и изменить переменную из другого нужно:

1. Найти обьект с инстансом второго скрипта. (лучше всего в делать это в Start() методе)
2. Взять у него скрипт (лучше всего в делать это в Start() методе)
3. Изменить нужную переменную в данном инстансе.

   `НазваниеСкрипта InstanceOfSomeScript;
   public void Start()
   {
       var InstanceOfSomeScript = GameObject.Find("ИмяОбьектаИзДереваОбьектов").GetComponent<НазваниеСкрипта>;
   }`

и, сосбственно последний пункт

`InstanceOfSomeScript.SomePublicIntVar = 10;`